# How can i solve this recursion

Tags: java, algorithm

This code is to find a peak number of an array with integer numbers
The problem is that i get an error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7`.

```
public long DivideAndConquer(int lo,int hi)
{
  int mid=((lo+hi)-1)/2;
   if(myarray[mid]>=myarray[mid-1]&&myarray[mid]>= myarray[mid+1])
     return myarray[mid];
   else if (myarray[mid-1]>= myarray[mid])
     return DivideAndConquer(lo,mid-1);
   else if (myarray[mid]<=myarray[mid+1])
     return DivideAndConquer(mid+1,hi);
return 99;

}
```

A peak number is a number which is bigger than their neighbors and if I am at the end of the array or at the beginning then I have to look only for the previews element.

I think I get this error because if my element in last position is bigger than previews then is a peak.  For example my last position is 9 then I have `myarray[9] > myarray[8]` then is a peak, but in the first if statement it look also for `myarray[9+1]` which I don't have so it gives me this error.

I can't remove `&&` for the first statement and add "or" (`||`) because then I get a wrong answer.  Any ideas please?

Comment: Are you sure you understood what comparison is going on there?

Comment: You're not passing the element you want to search. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think this would be easier if you specified what input you are using when you are getting the error, e.g.: `int[] myarray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` Also, it would be good if you explain exactly what `hi` and `lo` is supposed to be. I thought that `lo` would initially be the index of the first item in the array and `hi` would be the index of the last item in the array. But then the calculation for `mid` does not make sense. E.g. if there are 5 items: `((lo+hi)-1)/2 = ((0+4)-1)/2 = 3/2 = 1` But the index of the middle item is 2.

Comment: yes the lo is the index of the first item and the hi is the index of the last. I know that i am wrong for the -1 because now i understand exactly what u are saying to me. Lets say we find the middle of the array. If myarray[mid-1]<myarray[mid]>array[mid+1] then i want to return the element but if myarray[mid] is not bigger then i have to check which side is bigger and throw away the rest of the array.

Comment: Also my problem i think is that when it goes at the end of the array and specific for the last element then it goes back to the first if and check myarray[mid+1] and that time it gives me an error because am already at the last position and i cant check the position mid+1 because it does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Just like you said, the problem is that your implementation tries to look at the index `mid + 1`, when `mid` is the last item in the array. You need to handle this case. Something like the following:

```
public long DivideAndConquer(int lo,int hi){
    int mid = (lo+hi) / 2; //Modified to select the middle item
    if(mid + 1 >= myarray.length){
        //TODO: Handle the case when mid is the index of the last item in the array
    } else if(mid - 1 < 0){
        //TODO: Handle the case when mid is the index of the first item in the array
    } else if(myarray[mid]>=myarray[mid-1]&&myarray[mid]>= myarray[mid+1]){
        return myarray[mid];
    } else if (myarray[mid-1]>= myarray[mid]){
        return DivideAndConquer(lo,mid-1);
    } else if (myarray[mid]<=myarray[mid+1]){
        return DivideAndConquer(mid+1,hi);'
    }
    return Long.MIN_VALUE; //Probably a more suitable error indicator than 99
    //Alternatively, an exception could be thrown
}
```

If you use the approach suggested above, be particularly careful when implementing the handling of the `mid - 1 < 0` and `mid + 1 >= myarray.length` cases. You might need some special handling of the cases when `myarray.length` is only `1` or `2`.

Comment: i know that i can solve it also with this way but i can use only recursion. am sure that it can be done but i dont find the solution.

Comment: @user2346073 Uhm... Your recursion covers one base case (when the peak is in the interior of the array). However, you are completely missing the recursion base case when the algorithm has reached the beginning or the end of the array. Those are the base cases that I suggested you should add in my proposal above. The algorithm is still recursive though. The only difference is that this variety covers all the necessary base cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not considering the correctness of the algorithm, I came to the following changes for indexing safely:

```
public long DivideAndConquer(int lo,int hi)
{
    int mid=(lo+hi)/2; // Valid range
    if((lo<mid||myarray[mid]>=myarray[mid-1])
                 &&(hi>mid||myarray[mid]>= myarray[mid+1]))
       return myarray[mid];
    else if (lo<mid&&yarray[mid-1]>= myarray[mid])
       return DivideAndConquer(lo,mid-1);
    else if (hi>mid&&myarray[mid]<=myarray[mid+1])
       return DivideAndConquer(mid+1,hi);
    return 99;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work like this. It send me back only the middle number

Comment: @user2346073 You should know what you want before you expect something. You're logic is not correct.

Comment: I make that recursion to check if the neighbors of that element is smaller than the specific element. The problem at the code is that the last element it looks for the array[mid+1] which is not exists because the size of the array is 7 and if i look for the array[mid+1] is 8. The last time i dont want to check for the array[mid+1] because if the last element is bigger than the previews then it would be ok to return that element

Answer (score 0):

When implementing such a decicision cascade like in your "if-else-if-"... construction one has to make sure that every case is handled.

Also you have to make sure that any calculated array index is valid for the given array. This requirement may introduce some more "if" statements.

In your text, you wrote "if I am at the end of the array or at the beginning", but in your code there are no "if-statements" checking these conditions.

Comment: i dont check that condition because i use the divide and conquer and the last time when i divide i have to only look the previews element and if is bigger then i must return that element

Comment: your code doesn't do what you described in your text. As the others already said: it is unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to find a peak from an array with n elements.

Comment: And you want to achieve this by DivideAndConquer. But besides the range checks, your code is also missing the combining phase of a typical Divide and Conquer algorithm.

Comment: yes i have an array of n elements. I find the middle of the array and if is bigger than its neighbors then i return the element else if is not bigger i check the element at n-1 and n+1 to check which is bigger and then if i found that n-1 is bigger i divide the array and check only at the left side else i check only at the right side of the array.

Comment: Also my problem i think is that when it goes at the end of the array and specific for the last element then it goes back to the first if and check myarray[mid+1] and that time it gives me an error because am already at the last position and i cant check the position mid+1 because it does not exist